# INSERT INTO...SELECT, and UPDATE from SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm using MySQL's `INSERT INTO...SELECT` structure:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2, col3)
   SELECT otbl.col4, obtl.col5, atbl.col6 FROM other_table otbl
   INNER JOIN another_table atbl
      ON atbl.id = otbl.some_id
   WHERE obtl.col7 = 0;
```

In the same query, I want to "toggle on" `col7 = 1` wherever the `SELECT` matched. Possible?

Comment: Do I understand you right that you want your statement to _also_ UPDATE obtl.col7 to 1 when your insert into some_table happens?

Comment: @yhw42, yes! exactly. and the INSERT has to use WHERE obt1.col7 before that update is made, obviously.

Comment: ... hmmm I'm with Umbrella in the "two queries + transaction" camp  ... Can you explain why that wouldn't work for you?

Comment: convenience and performance. if it's not possible, it's not possible...but had to ask

Comment: On which condition do you want to set col7 to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is **No**.  I have wanted to do similar things, like update a user's login time while selecting their details.  In your case, you would have to have two queries, with the update being second.  If you need to ensure nothing occurs between them, consider a transaction.

Comment: +1 on transactions, but when tables get big, one query is always better than two. you're probably right though. i'll leave the question open for a bit just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger on the other_table like

other_table

```
CREATE TRIGGER other_Trigger
AFTER insert ON some_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update other_table set col7=1 where some.id=new.id
END
```